# Snyk test returns Failed to test pip project error

Tags: snyk

I'm running security scan with [Snyk CLI](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360003812538-Install-the-Snyk-CLI) for python project. Unfortunately `snyk test` command returns **Failed to test pip project** error. What am I missing, `snyk test` works just fine while scanning `npm` project ?

```sh
$ snyk test --file=requirements.txt
Failed to test pip project
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the cause basically you need to do two things:

- Make sure that packages that your project uses are installed.
- Make sure that you are using correct python.

#### Solution

```sh
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
$ snyk test --file=requirements.txt --command=python3
```

#### Info

You can bypass missing python packages by passing the `--allow-missing` pip parameter through snyk by using the additional `--` argument.

```sh
$ snyk test --file=requirements.txt --command=python3 -- --allow-missing
```

#### Docs

```
-- [COMPILER_OPTIONS]
    Pass extra arguments directly to Gradle or Maven. E.g. snyk test
    -- --build-cache

Python options
    --command=COMMAND
        Indicate which specific Python commands to use based  on  Python
        version.  The  default is python which executes your systems de-
        fault python version. Run 'python -V' to find out  what  version
        is  it.  If you are using multiple Python versions, use this pa-
        rameter to specify the correct Python command for execution.

        Default: python Example: --command=python3
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had to add `--file=requirements.txt --command=python3` to the VSCode additional parameters field, under the snyk extension settings wheel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Snyk and VScode, and you open a repo that has a Python VirtualEnv, you can get this error in your VScode terminal window.

- [Error] Open Source Security test failed for "/home/{user}/path/to/repo". Failed to test pip project

Fix for VScode:

1. Close that VScode window.
2. From a terminal, navigate to the top folder of that repo.
3. Run the command to activate the virtual env

   - Example: `. .venv/bin/activate`
4. Open VScode for that folder

   - Example: run `code .`

The Snyk Open Source Security test should run without that error now.

Comment: This issue worked for me, though not quite the same.  I got the `Recommended packages could not be found` error but closing VSCode, activating the environment **before** restarting VSCode worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

snyk monitor command will also return undefined if it is not ran with

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
snyk test --file=requirements.txt --command=python3
snyk monitor --file=requirements.txt --command=python3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtual environments, then make sure you have activated the venv with

```bash
. venv/Scripts/activate
```

Then try running Snyk Test again.

Snyk monitor and other cli commands should work from that! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).